# Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a NodeJS app in Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everytime I deploy the app I get following error (in logs):

```
2016-09-06T15:56:48.332Z] INFO  [17369] : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"/bin/sh: npm: command not found. \ncontainer_command 01-install-dependencies in .ebextensions/install.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":127,"events":[]}]}
```

Any idea what must be causing it?

Comment: Can you paste /var/log/eb-activity.log

Comment: What is in your `.ebextensions/install.config` file?

Comment: Here is /var/log/eb-activity.log: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/2WIN

Comment: My install.config is: container_commands:
  01-install-dependencies:
    command: "npm install"

Comment: The error message is clearly saying it can't find the `npm` command when it tries to run `01-install-dependencies`. Perhaps you need to give it the full path to npm? In your activity log it looks like `npm install` is already being run, so maybe you don't need `01-install-dependencies`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deploying a NodeJS application to elastic beanstalk `npm install` is run automatically for you. You haven't posted the contents of your `01-install-dependencies` but guessing from the name and the error message that script runs `npm install`.

I did some investigation a while back into which npm scripts are automatically run by elastic beanstalk - [npm scripts on elastic beanstalk](http://clarkie.io/nodejs/2015/06/25/npm-scripts-on-elastic-beanstalk.html)